# Custom Header are dropping during load testing on AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, kubernetes, aws-lambda

I have integrated lambda with AWS API Gateway to add custom headers before sending the request to the AWS ALB. I have checked the all the flow using postman tool everything is working fine, but when we are doing performance testing using Jmeter, we have observed that for some requests AWS ALB dropping the custom header from the requests.
Also i have checked **Drop invalid header fields also disabled**

What can be the issue here?

I have integrated lambda with AWS API Gateway to add custom headers before sending the request to the AWS ALB. I have checked the all the flow using postman tool everything is working fine, but when we are doing performance testing using Jmeter, we have observed that for some requests AWS ALB dropping the custom header from the requests.

I am expecting a proper response during the performance testing but for some requests custom headers are dropping from AWS ALB.

Comment: So it shows in Postman but not JMeter? Are you replicating the same request? Can you show some code?

Comment: In the JMeter also we have 99% success during testing but for that 1% AWS ALB dropping the custom headers during the performance testing.